# Yii2 nested pjax

Tags: yii2, pjax

I have page with tabs (which are actually links handled by parent pjax). Which loads the tab content via pjax calls.

In one of the tabs, I have a gridview which is inside a pjax container. So that makes it a nested one. 
The problem is that the nested one when loaded and inserted into the page, does not include it's own javascript i.e:

```
jQuery(document).pjax("#history-gridview a", "#history-pjax", {"push":true,"replace":false,"timeout":5000,"scrollTo":false});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `renderAjax()` when requesting the tab page (or content).  I do something like this:

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) return $this->renderAjax('myview');
else return $this->render('myview');
```

However, it may not fix your problem. I've found if I navigate **tabs** and a grid is loaded dynamically in the tab (with its own pjax container), then any interaction with **grid** sort and filter tries to reload from the outer (pjax tab) container even with **skipOuterContainers** set to **true**.

On a side note, the developers are thinking of dropping pjax support completely  [as per here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/wiki/Plan-for-next-major-versions) as well as how asset bundles work.

---

**The question remains:**

> How to create super fast performance like an SPA (single page app)
>   without Angular2 or similar? The grid container within a tab container
>   is the perfect example which, if could be achieved (catering for
>   back/forward buttons, initialisation scripts) would be awesome.